# Regex to get number after matched pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have created a regex pattern to match the following:

```
'x': 10.61                # Any number, can be negative
```

**Regex**: `'x':\s[-+]?\d*\.*\d+`

However, I would like to get **only the number**, and so have attempted the following:

```
re.findall("'x':\K\s[-+]?\d*\.*\d+", info)
```

But from what I understand `\K` doesn't work on python.

Is there any **alternative** that would match e.g: `10.61` only?

Comment: You could store your number into a capturing group and access this.

Comment: What would `\K` do if it worked the way you wanted?

Comment: @Robᵩ in PCRE (and other flavours) \K is a match reset, omitting everything that has been matched before from the match.

Comment: It seems to me the closest functional match to `\K` is *positive lookbehind assertion*: `(?<='x':)\s[-+]?\d*\.\d+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
info = "'x': 10.61"
items = re.findall("'x':\s([-+]?\d*\.*\d+)", info)
print(items[0]) # 10.61
```

Comment: The regex is almost like yours but i get the number in parentesies () so when the regex exec each parenthesies is captured in array. So the first element will be items[0] the second parenthesies if exists will be items[1] and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If your input is always `some char: wanted num`, you could split the returned string by the delimiter `:` and grab the string from the returned list at position one.

```
result = re.findall("'x':\s[-+]?\d*\.*\d+", info)
digits = [ i.split(":")[1] for i in result ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach with `re.match()` function:

```
info = "'x': 10.61"
m = re.match(r"'x':\s*?([+-]?\d+([.]\d+)?)", info)
num = m.group(1)
print(num)  # 10.61
```